# Python 2.7.6 + unicode_literals - UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I'm trying to print the following unicode string but I'm receiving a `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte` error. Can you please help form this query so it can print the unicode string properly?

```
>>> from __future__ import unicode_literals
>>> ts='now'
>>> free_form_request='[EXID(이엑스아이디)] 위아래 (UP&DOWN) MV'
>>> nick='me'

>>> print('{ts}: free form request {free_form_request} requested from {nick}'.format(ts=ts,free_form_request=free_form_request.encode('utf-8'),nick=nick))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xec in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Try [ignoring the errors](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode): `free_form_request.encode('utf-8', errors='ignore')`

Comment: @PeterWood This won't work, the problem happens when the string is decoded after being encoded. Note that the string is already unicode due to the `unicode_literals` import.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco Ah, I missed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what happen when you construct this string:

```
'{ts}: free form request {free_form_request} requested from {nick}'.format(ts=ts,free_form_request=free_form_request.encode('utf-8'),nick=nick)
```

1. `free_form_request` is `encode`-d into a **byte string** using `utf-8` as the encoding. This works because `utf-8` can represent `[EXID(이엑스아이디)] 위아래 (UP&DOWN) MV`.
2. However, the format string (`'{ts}: free form request {free_form_request} requested from {nick}'`) is a **unicode string** (because of  imported `from __future__ import unicode_literals`).
3. You can't use **byte strings** as format arguments for a **unicode string**, so Python attempts to `decode` the byte string created in 1. to create a **unicode string** (which would be valid as an format argument).
4. Python attempts the `decode`-ing using the default encoding, which is `ascii`, and fails, because the byte string is a `utf-8` byte string that includes byte values that don't make sense in `ascii`.
5. Python throws a `UnicodeDecodeError`.

Note that while the code is obviously doing something here, this would actually not throw an exception on Python 3, which would instead substitute the `repr` of the byte string (the `repr` being a unicode string).

---

To fix your issue, just pass unicode strings to `format`.

That is, don't do step 1. where you encoded `free_form_request` as a byte string: keep it as a unicode string by removing `.encode(...)`:

```
'{ts}: free form request {free_form_request} requested from {nick}'.format(
    ts=ts, 
    free_form_request=free_form_request, 
    nick=nick)
```

---

Note Padraic Cunningham's answer in the comments as well.

Comment: I have the block of code from the original question in a larger function. It turns out something I had imported re-writes the print function and can't handle unicode strings properly. Unfortunately, my workaround is encode('ascii', errors='ignore') and drop the unicode characters and just deal with that.

Comment: @PrestonConnors Then you should encode the formatted string, not the format arguments. Just do: `print('...'.format(...).encode('utf-8'))`

Comment: While the original code would not throw an exception on Python 3, Python 3 doesn't implicitly decode the byte string back to Unicode (step 3), so what is printed is the `repr` of the byte string encoding.  To correctly work on Python 3 the `encode` would still have to be removed.